# Google map displayed in my Ubuntu machine ,not displayed in Xp machine

Tags: android

I am developed application with google map in android 2.2 version using eclipse in  ubuntu machine.In that case I can get the google map as well as the location perfectly.

But now i have to run that same apps in Xp machine,there also  am having android 2.2 .The apps run properly but the google map not displayed ,only white screen with boxes displayed.

can any one help me ,what are the changes i need to apply in my apps to get the same output in xp machine too?

Thanks & Regards,
Lakshmanan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your different machines are not using the same keys to compile the application. Google maps API needs you to generate a key to use the service, and that key needs to match the one you use to sign your application. Consequently, you need to sign your application with the same key on your linux and your windows machine. Just copy your key repository over from your linux machine and try using that to sign your application.